# Passing form data from one web page to another with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

i found few similar questions here but from answers i didn't get the whole picture of how should work.

I have a subscription form in a page:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php/register"> 
<fieldset> 
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" /> 
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" /> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="&gt;&gt;" /> 
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

when a user a user click the submit button is lead to a page with the full registering form, where i need to have few fields populated with the data sent from previous page form. this is a preview of few fields from the form of the second page:

```
<form id="register" name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<fieldset>  
<li><label>*First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
</li>

<li>
<label>*Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" />
</li>

<li>
<label>*Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
</li>

<li>
<label>*Confirm Email</label>
<input type="text" id="confirm-email" name="confirm_email" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Street Address</label>
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" />

<li class="full-width">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />                    
</li>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

the php is not my strong point, so if you can be more detailed in answer is great for me.

thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using a single form to capture all the data you want?  Why fill out one form, only to have them default values in a second form?

Comment: @Moo-Juice Im sure he has his reasons..

Comment: @Jonah Having a reason to do it doesn't automatically make it a good idea. It's illogical, and likely annoying for the user, to have a form that simply serves to populate a subsection of another form.

Comment: the first form is like a preview form and is placed in a footer area. the second one, is a register form with many fields and have its page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say for security reasons, do not use Get method "`$_GET[]`" as people described, keep POST as you have it.

All you need to do on register/ page is get all the values passed on using the POST method and populate them into your HTML. So the second form should look like:

```
    <form id="register" name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
    <fieldset>  
    <li><label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="<?=$_POST[first_name]?>" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <label>*Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="<?=$_POST[last_name]?>" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <label>*Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?=$_POST[email]?>" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <label>*Confirm Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="confirm-email" name="confirm_email" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <label>Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="<?=$_POST[address]?>" />

    <li class="full-width">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />                    
    </li>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Above, I am using shorthand version of "echo" and php tags, if you do not have that enabled under php.ini, please change "" to `"; ?>`. Also, script will not populate "confirm" email as I assume you would like the user to retype that.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two methods

1. Store the values of the first form in a cookie, and the process code can retrieve the values from the cookie
2. make the form action 'Get' so that the data is passed on to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="register.php"> 
<fieldset> 
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" /> 
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" /> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="&gt;&gt;" /> 
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

`register.php`

```
<form id="register" name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<fieldset>  
<li><label>*First Name</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['first_name'];?>" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
</li>

<li>
<label>*Last Name</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['last_name'];?>" id="last_name" name="last_name" />
</li>

<li>
<label>*Email</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>" id="email" name="email" />
</li>

<li>
<label>*Confirm Email</label>
<input type="text" id="confirm-email" name="confirm_email" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Street Address</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['address'];?>" id="address" name="address" />

<li class="full-width">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />                    
</li>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Finally service the post in `send_contact.php` as you wish

Comment: hi sherif, not working. the fields from page 2 show for instance: " first_name" instead the data from first form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_POST values from the first form in the page handling the submit of the first form and print them in the new form as:

```
<?php
  echo '<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="' . htmlentities($_POST['email']) . '"/>
?>
```