# Taking data to a new window with jquery

Tags: jquery

is possible to take form data to another html page with jquery.

Would the code below be a start?

```
function login(){

var data = $('#logon').serialize();
$.post('mainApp.html', data, function() { alert('done'); }

);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6913970/235710

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to a new window by sending it to the server, by using cookies or using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery ajax form plugin to let the form do all the work, and you just specify the options that you want.

[JQuery Ajax Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: will this work on jquery mobile? as form action with php script didnt

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used it for mobile purposes.  The example shows that you can use it as a form with PHP.