# how to send data from one web page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't how to ask this question but if their are duplicates send me that. Their are several .php files i have made

content.php, show.php and showFilteredResult.php .

content.php sends the start date and end date to the show.php and it returns the the orderIds which are of that date

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var srt = $("#cal1Date1").val();
    var end = $("#cal1Date2").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/show.php",
        data: {
            srt: srt,
            end: end
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (response) {

            $rtndata = response.responseText;
            var dat1a = jQuery.parseJSON($rtndata);
            var result = dat1a.OrderID;
            console.log(result[0]); // send this result
        }
    });
});
```

now I want to send this $result with orderids to  showFilteredResult.php where then i can make tables etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Can't you do that in show.php? I think it's silly send request from frontend to backend to get data and then those data send back and say to backend 'Hey, do also this!' (if you are not changing them of course)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing form data from one web page to another with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913970/passing-form-data-from-one-web-page-to-another-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip the AJAX and just use request parameters (GET or POST).

cal1Date1 and cal1Date2 are input fields I assume. Wrap them in a form and post the values to a PHP form handler that could handle the lookup and display. No need for the AJAX middle-man here.

Comment: could you point me toward a tutorial or something i don't have experience with php or web design for that matter.

Comment: I suppose this is a decent starter tutorial about PHP form processing. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: No prob, glad I could help :)

Comment: i wanted to ask one more thing i don't want create another question

Comment: look at this image [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2akk4l4.png) their are more then 15 col. in my tables and i don't know how shorten their length i have tried the below code ' <td width='70px' align='center'>  <input type='text' id='txt_orderid_".$i."'   value=" . $row["Order ID"]. " disabled> </td> 
            '

Answer (score 1):

Just make a similar Ajax request to `showFilteredResult.php` I would have them in a separate function.

```
function  showFilteredResult($result){
    $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost/showFilteredResult.php",
                data: {
                    result:$result
                        },
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                complete:function(response){
                           $rtndata=response.responseText;
                           var dat1a=jQuery.parseJSON($rtndata);
                           var result=dat1a.OrderID;
                           console.log(result[0]);// do something with the data returned from showFilteredResult.php
    }
});

}
```

and from the request that you have just call that funciton like

```
     ...    $rtndata=response.responseText;
                           var dat1a=jQuery.parseJSON($rtndata);
                           var result=dat1a.OrderID;
                           console.log(result[0]);// send this result
                           showFilteredResult(result[0]);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead making another request to server , you have another option to do that. Let's say you get orderId from show.php before sending back , right ? Then you can use this orderId to do what u want such as query which u have written in showFilteredResult.php . then return back to client for final result . In that way you can eliminate the unnecessary http request.